# DataFrame is confused, throws "'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Getting kind of an obscure error while performing actions on a DataFrame. Context goes like this:

```
res2 = group.z.agg(['mean', 'std', len])
res2 = res2.drop(res2[np.isnan(res2.len)].index).drop(res2[res2.len <= 5.].index)
print(type(res2))
res2 = res2.transform(uncert)
```

First I'm doing this. The print gives

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

So far so good. Now the 'uncert' function I'm calling in transform looks like this:

```
def uncert(df):
   values = []
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
       print(row.mean, row.std)
       #values.append(ufloat(row['mean'], row['std']))
   #df['uval'] = Series(values, index=df.index)
   return df
```

Commented out the two lines to check what was going on. Now, ithrows an error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e41277533a08> in <module>()
     66     res2 = res2.drop(res2[np.isnan(res2.len)].index).drop(res2[res2.len <= 5.].index)
     67     print(type(res2))
---> 68     res2 = res2.transform(uncert)
     69 
     70     print('Method 2:\n', res2, "\n\n")

.
.
.


<ipython-input-6-e41277533a08> in uncert(df)
     13 def uncert(df):
     14     values = []
---> 15     for index, row in df.iterrows():
     16         print(row.mean, row.std)
     17         #values.append(ufloat(row['mean'], row['std']))

.
.
.
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'", 'occurred at index mean')
```

Aaaand this kind of doesn't make sense to me, since I am performing the action on a DataFrame object. The frame looks like this btw:

```
                     mean       std    len
(-0.001, 29.409]    2.198392  0.027809   40.0
(29.409, 75.024]    1.950194  0.008493   49.0
(78.625, 203.464]   1.766212  0.014613  145.0
(205.264, 215.468]  1.604461  0.008790   10.0
```

Anybody got a clue or experienced something similar?

Comment: You are not performing that in a DataFrame, but in a Series. When you use `transform` and pass a function to it, pandas will call this function passing a series as argument. This series will be  either each column, or each row (depending on if you state `axis=0` or `axis=1` respectively)

Comment: Great, that helped! :)

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue at the moment however I don't quite understand how @RafaelC comment addresses the issue. Please elaborate on how to fix the issue.

Comment: The `transform` method uses a different object of the `pandas` library, a `series`. It's pretty similar and prints similarly, which is why I got confused thinking `uncert` in the above example was called on the `DataFrame`, but `transform` calls the passed function `uncert` on each row or column individually, which are `Series` objects and thus do not have the `iterrows` method. @Kusi